# Media Queries not working for smaller screen sizes

Tags: css, media-queries

```
/***** BIGGER SCREEN *****/

@media screen and (min-width: 1367px) {

#body-wrapper {
max-width: 1367px;
margin: auto;

}

}

/** IPHONE **/

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) { 

#logo {
    display: none;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 200px;
}
}
```

Trying to get a simple media iphone query to work, I have tried everything but it makes no changes on my browser/phone, I have meta viewport and file is working fine. I have made query changes in other sizes which work, for some reason once I go below 700px nothing changes no matter what I do..

Comment: where is html code??

Comment: thanks for answering, html code is really long, as you can see I have a display none css but it still displays, I have done other things like increasing sizes and moving things and nothing happens, Im losing hope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use max-width only

```
.regular-classes {
    ...
}

/* narrower than 1367px - overrides all attributes from the regular selectors */
@media screen and (max-width: 1367px) {
    ...
}

/* narrower than 667px - overridse all attributes from the queries above */
@media only screen
and (max-device-width : 667px) { 
    ...
}

/* narrower than 375px - overrides all attributes from the queries above*/
@media (max-device-width : 375px) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: uuuugh still nothing changes

Comment: It wont even change the font color

Comment: my min-width 1367 is working tho... it doesnt make sense

Comment: ok actually I got it to work, Im not sure what the problem was but this answer was the most helpful

Answer (score 0):

**Update css**

```
    @media only screen 
and (min-width : 375px) 
and (max-width : 667px) { 

#logo {
    display: none;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
}
```

**Live Demo** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/2oabh5ts/)

**Try to resize window and change effect in Fiddle**

Comment: sorry but what is fiddle?

Comment: hmmm seems to work backwards in fiddle, logo goes away in the larger size screen but appears in smaller screen

Comment: i hope you can understand in media query . and your required code insert into media query..i have jast put example . you can put in your development